# How to make a legacy application software written with full fledged m/w classes be adapted to work on a subset of the same m/w classes

Tags: java, classloader

I have an already developed Application software(Framework) structure. It was actually developed on top of a full set of available middleware classes.

Now we have got one requirement like, this application framework should work on a subset of the previously available middleware classes as well.

So what it means is like, we should make the current software adapted to work independently on

- middleware jar containing all classes
- middleware jar containing only some of the classes(other classes
  will not be loaded)

The real problem is all the getInstances and class usages of the unavailable classes in the current software structure should be blocked from happening, otherwise this will be throwing our class not found exceptions.

So what is the best approach to solve this problem?

What I was having in my mind was something like, having a class which will decide the mode, on a boot up, in which the software is going to run and then selectively do the class instantiations on the mode selected.

But this is going to flood the software with if-else conditions on the mode.

Please post your ideas and pointers so that I can solve this issue in a better way which will give me more flexibility in the future.

---

Update:

Why I need to have my software structure work like this is, I will be having two products with same application software, but with two sets of m/w in each product(based on the produc features).

For eg. The full product will be working with all set of classes and low end version of the product working in the subset of m/w classes

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Provide your own implementation for the classes that are missing in the *middleware jar containing only some of the classes*.

The other way would be a fully fledged refactoring.

Comment: I dont want to do that because, those classes anyways are not needed for my appplication to work when in such a mode(a mode with those classes absent)

Comment: Did you mean stubbing them?

Comment: Use whatever implementation meets your requirements.